# SQLAlchemy with QueuePool and two processes: Is it alright to close shared connection on checkout?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

I am using flask, flask_SQLAlchemy and postgres. Two single threaded processes are serving my application in development. At first I had the following code snippet:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {'pool_size': 1, 'pool_pre_ping': True, 'pool_recycle': 280}
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()
```

This one yielded an OperationalError while testing my API. I found three references [1] [2] [3] explaining the issue. They state that after forking, two processes are sharing the same connection originating from create_all() which happens to be the cause of the problem. So I utilised one of the already provided solutions to remove a shared connection from the pools upon checkout:

```
def add_engine_pidguard(engine):
    """Add multiprocessing guards.

    Forces a connection to be reconnected if it is detected
    as having been shared to a sub-process.

    """

    @event.listens_for(engine, "connect")
    def connect(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
        connection_record.info['pid'] = os.getpid()

    @event.listens_for(engine, "checkout")
    def checkout(dbapi_connection, connection_record, connection_proxy):
        pid = os.getpid()
        if connection_record.info['pid'] != pid:
            warnings.warn(
                "Parent process %(orig)s forked (%(newproc)s) with an open "
                "database connection, "
                "which is being discarded and recreated." %
                {"newproc": pid, "orig": connection_record.info['pid']})
            connection_record.connection = connection_proxy.connection = None

            raise exc.DisconnectionError(
                "Connection record belongs to pid %s, "
                "attempting to check out in pid %s" %
                (connection_record.info['pid'], pid)
            )
```

and `add_engine_pidguard(db.engine)` right after `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`. This approach finally gets rid of the error, but

```
SELECT *
    FROM pg_stat_activity
    WHERE query NOT LIKE '%%FROM pg_stat_activity%%';
```

shows that, while the first connection gets thrown away off the pools, still remains in the database. So I finally end up with three connections. I find it kinda scary that the first connection seems to get used for the pre_pring according to the "query" field of the prior SQL-Statement. In order to prevent multiple processes sharing the same connection again, I added:

```
if not dbapi_connection.closed:
    dbapi_connection.close()
```

right before raising a DisconnectionError in my `def checkout(dbapi_connection, connection_record, connection_proxy):`

After that, only two connections are appearing in my database and no errors are occurring so far.

Now I kindly ask, is this safe to do so? I fear it's possible for the two processes trying to close the connection at the same time.

Edit: I know using a NullPool instead of a QueuePool would solve issues like that. However, a NullPool would result into costly operations like creating and closing database connection for each request and I am not quite sure how bad this can get in case of many requests.

[1] https://davidcaron.dev/sqlalchemy-multiple-threads-and-processes/

[2] https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing

[3] https://docs-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/ko/latest/faq/connections.html